# MS Access: Multi-User Application: send msgbox to specific user

Tags: ms-access, vba

I don't know if my idea is possible to solve with MS Access. The requirement:

I have one centralized DATA-database and several Client-Databases. It will be used to maintain a rescue team in our company. Each one has to press a button in his client and in the reception client is visible who is available in case of an emergency.
It even shows who is in which corner of the building the rescue person is.

Now, it's in human nature that in evening People forget to logout. Plan is to define a usual end of work time. The reception client verifies every 5 Minute if someone reaches his end of work time and can set him as out of office.
Problem is, perhaps Mr. X works today not until 17h as usuall - today he is available until 20h. 
So, a message should Pop up 15 Min before his end-of work and ask him if he goes by time or not. If he answers to work longer, a flag should remove him from this function today.

Solution is almost 70% developped. Problem is now the little point, how to pop-up the message to the right user. One Idea is to check a message table if there is a message for him. 
But, i don't like to make to much LAN traffic... if each client ask every 5 minutes the DATA DB if there is a message for him.

Has some one an idea?

Best regards
Roland

Answer (score 0):

Polling a single table every 5 minutes should generate virtually no load. I've used a similar solution that polls every minute without any trouble on a networked database with ~20 users.

You can, of course, pull in these messages once, since they will fire at a set time, and then just raise them at that time.

You can just have a hidden form that's bound to a specific table, uses a filter on the username, and requery every x seconds, tests if there's a message ready, and then displays it.

Alternatively, you can pull in messages once, and have a hidden form that checks on timer if it's time to raise that message.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I rod your answer and had the idea to put the reminder logic to the individual client itself. Start a reminder 15 Min before end-of-day time and set an ignore-flag if he is longer working.